# In Mac OS X Snow Leopard, how can one file's permissions be matched to another?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, macos

I need to make the permissions of a file exactly match the permissions of another file in OS X 10.6.

I don't see `getfacl` or `setfacl` as suggested in some other posts for Linux. And, it doesn't look like `chown`/`chmod` have a `--reference` option in Snow Leopard.

What is the equivalent on the Mac?

Comment: Do you want full ACLs or just regular UNIX file permissions?

Comment: Full ACLs. I need the files to match exactly.

Answer (score 5):

This one works:

```
chmod `stat -f %A srcFile` dstFile
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Hmm works for me. Which version do you have?

Comment: While `-f %A` work for me, it seems to be undocumented; `-f %Lp` does the same i.e ``chmod `stat -f %Lp srcFile` dstFile``

Answer (score 2):

OK, so for a straight ACL copy, I can't see a single command. However, you can put this in a script or function:

```
ls -le source | sed -En '/^ [[:digit:]]+: / { s/^ [[:digit:]]+: //; p; }' | chmod -E dest
```

eg.

```
function copyacl()
{
  ls -le "$1" \
    | sed -En '/^ [[:digit:]]+: / { s/^ [[:digit:]]+: //; p; }' \
    | chmod -E "$2"
}

$ copyacl sourcefile destfile
```

I feel like that *sed* script could be improved, but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls -le` to see any acls a file has associated with it.

Use `chmod` to change or remove the acls.  There are plenty of examples toward the end of the [chmod man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/chmod.1.html) to guide you.

Mac OS has a separate set of file access flags, apparently inherited from the BSDs.  You can see those with `ls -lO` (that's dash ell oh) and modify them with [`chflags`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/chflags.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the thought, Kyle. However, I was hoping NOT to have to do all that. I'm looking for just a simple permissions copy like the ones noted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are ask about standard UNIX permissions or for ACL's.  Many versions of `chmod` have a `--reference` option to take the permissions of another file:

```
chmod --reference=~/backup/file ~/newfile
```

But you'll need to check the options for `chmod` on your Mac:

```
chmod --help
```

Comment: I noted in my post that the --reference option is not there.

Comment: --reference doesn't work for me on MacOS (11.6 now, but also 10.15.x and 11.5)